# OS family 4 Azure Worker Role

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net, iis-8.5

My application is hosted in Azure Web Role, whereas WCF services are hosted on Worker role, these services are using TCP protocol. I am migrating all of these from OS family 2 to OS family 4 and from SDK 1.7 to SDK 2.3.

However, when I say Instance count as 2 for Worker Role, my application gets very slow or even stops responding. Sometimes even the default page doesn't load, but with Instance count as 1, the application works completely fine with no issues and good performance.

Note: Application is hosted on 2 Instances all the time.

What am I missing? Do I need to tweak any settings to make this work on 2 instances?

Comment: Is it possible the page is somehow redirecting to itself, (repeatedly)? That can cause symptoms similar to what you describe.

Comment: when I try hosting the application on local machine on IIS and run it without emulator, consuming the services deployed on Azure (instance count = 2), it is working fine.